# Cumulative Sum When Order Was Placed in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, sum, amazon-redshift, cumulative-sum

I have an orders table with datetime when an order was placed, and when it was completed:

| orderid | userid | price | status | createdat | doneat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 128 | 100 | completed | 2/16/21 18:40:45 | 2/21/21 07:59:46 |
| 2 | 128 | 150 | completed | 2/21/21 05:27:29 | 2/23/21 11:58:23 |
| 3 | 128 | 100 | completed | 9/3/21 08:38:14 | 9/10/21 14:24:35 |
| 4 | 5 | 100 | completed | 5/28/22 23:28:07 | 6/26/22 06:10:35 |
| 5 | 5 | 100 | canceled | 7/8/22 22:28:57 | 8/10/22 06:55:17 |
| 6 | 5 | 100 | completed | 7/25/22 13:46:38 | 8/10/22 06:57:20 |
| 7 | 5 | 5 | completed | 8/7/22 18:07:07 | 8/12/22 06:56:23 |

I would like to have a new column that is the cumulative total (sum price) per user when the order was created:

| orderid | userid | price | status | createdat | doneat | cumulative total when placed (per user) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 128 | 100 | completed | 2/16/21 18:40:45 | 2/21/21 07:59:46 | 0 |
| 2 | 128 | 150 | completed | 2/21/21 05:27:29 | 2/23/21 11:58:23 | 0 |
| 3 | 128 | 100 | completed | 9/3/21 08:38:14 | 9/10/21 14:24:35 | 250 |
| 4 | 5 | 100 | completed | 5/28/22 23:28:07 | 6/26/22 06:10:35 | 0 |
| 5 | 5 | 100 | canceled | 7/8/22 22:28:57 | 8/10/22 06:55:17 | 100 |
| 6 | 5 | 100 | completed | 7/25/22 13:46:38 | 8/10/22 06:57:20 | 100 |
| 7 | 5 | 5 | completed | 8/7/22 18:07:07 | 8/12/22 06:56:23 | 100 |

The logic is sum the price for each user for all orders that were completed before the current row's created at date. For orderid=2, although it's the user's 2nd order, there are no orders that were completed before its createdat datetime of 2/21/21 05:27:29, so the cumulative total when placed is 0.

The same for orderid in [5,6,7]. For those orders and that userid, the only order that was completed before their createdat dates is order 4, so their cumulative total when placed is 100.

In PowerBI the logic is like this:

```
SUMX (
filter(
orders, 
earlier orders.userid = orders.userid && orders.doneat < orders.createdat && order.status = 'completed'),
orders.price)
```

Would anyone have any hints of how to achieved this in postgresql?

I tried something like this and it didn't work.

```
select (case when o.doneat < o.createdat over (partition by o.userid, o.status order by o.createdat)
    then sum(o.price) over (partition by o.userid, o.status ORDER BY o.doneat asc ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
        end) as cumulativetotal_whenplaced
    from order o
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can duplicate each row into:

1. an "original" (which we'll decorate with a flag `keep = true`), that has an accounting value `val = 0` (so far), and a time `t = createdat`;
2. a "duplicate" (`keep = false`), that has the price to account for (if status is `'completed'`) as `val` and a time `t = doneat`.

Then it's just a matter of accounting for the right bits:

```sql
select orderid, userid, price, status, createdat, doneat, cumtot
from (
  select *, sum(val) over (partition by userid order by t, keep desc) as cumtot
  from (
    select *, createdat as t, 0 as val, true as keep from foo
    union all
    select *, doneat as t,
      case when status = 'completed' then price else 0 end as val,
      false as keep
    from foo
  ) as a
) as a
where keep
order by orderid;
```

Example: [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gKGqdZYPhQNXA4gaAHFgkC/0).

Note for RedShift: the window expression above needs to be replaced by:

```sql
   ...
   select *, sum(val) over (
     partition by userid order by t, keep desc
     rows unbounded preceding) as cumtot
   ...
```

Result for your data:

| orderid | userid | price | status | createdat | doneat | cumtot |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 128 | 100 | completed | 2021-02-16T18:40:45.000Z | 2021-02-21T07:59:46.000Z | 0 |
| 2 | 128 | 150 | completed | 2021-02-21T05:27:29.000Z | 2021-02-23T11:58:23.000Z | 0 |
| 3 | 128 | 100 | completed | 2021-09-03T08:38:14.000Z | 2021-09-10T14:24:35.000Z | 250 |
| 4 | 5 | 100 | completed | 2022-05-28T23:28:07.000Z | 2022-06-26T06:10:35.000Z | 0 |
| 5 | 5 | 100 | canceled | 2022-07-08T22:28:57.000Z | 2022-08-10T06:55:17.000Z | 100 |
| 6 | 5 | 100 | completed | 2022-07-25T13:46:38.000Z | 2022-08-10T06:57:20.000Z | 100 |
| 7 | 5 | 5 | completed | 2022-08-07T18:07:07.000Z | 2022-08-12T06:56:23.000Z | 100 |

**Note**: this type of accounting across time is actually robust to many corner-cases (various orders overlapping, some starting and finishing while others are still in process, etc.) It is the basis for a fast interval compaction algorithm that I should describe someday on SO.

Bonus: try to figure out why the partitioning window is ordered by `t` (fairly obvious) *and also by* `keep desc` (less obvious).

Comment: Hello Pierre, thank you for your quick reply. When I try to run it, it is asking for a frame clause for the order by. I'm working with was redshift, if that makes a difference in the postgresql language. Would you know which frame clause would suit? I tried a few but the cumtot shows as zero

Comment: I didn't realize you were using Redshift (I just added the tag to your question). There are some important differences between PostgreSQL and Redshift. For example, in window functions where the window has an `ORDER BY` (like in our query), then there must be a frame_clause to define the set of rows to consider. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Window_function_synopsis.html). I am not connected just now to a Redshift cluster, so I can't try immediately, but from the documentation I would add `unbounded preceding` to the window.

Comment: Hello Pierre, thank you. I tried unbounded preceding but for some reason it still shows as 0 for the cumtot, not sure how to troubleshoot

Comment: I tried (and edited my answer to include the specific mod for redshift). It works fine on the example.